# Writing USB Joystick for PIC18F using MikroC

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, usb-device

I'm using PIC18F2458 as USB Joystick HID. The program works, but I have few problems.

Right now, The USB is not detected If I write less than 5 values ( Throttle, X,Y, 4 buttons). The current problem is If I'm using an analog sensor for the throttle, other axis x,y getting read too, because they are going to be read from analog input and of course there is noise, so whenever I use a rotary resistor on the throttle usb input, I get other axis written too.

How can I fix that issue ?

second issue how would I add two throttle for the usb descriptor ?

Here is the current code:

```
unsigned int average(int channel)
{
 int samples = 16;
 unsigned int sum = 0;
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < samples; i++)
 {
 
     sum+=(Adc_Read(channel)>>2)-128;
 }
 sum = sum/16;
 return sum;
}

void analogo() {

    usb[0] = average(1);   // Get 10-bit results of AD conversion
    usb[1] = average(9);
    usb[2] = average(8);
}

void main(void){
                              // Disable comparators

 ADCON1  = 0x05;                         // Configure all ports with analog function as digital
 TRISA.RA1 =1;
 TRISB.RB2=1;
 TRISB.RB3 =1;
 
 HID_Enable(&readbuff,&writebuff);       // Enable HID communication

 //vl6180x_configure();

  while(1){
  analogo();
  USB_Polling_Proc();

    writebuff[0]=usb[0];         // throttle
    writebuff[1]=usb[1];        // X axis
    writebuff[2]=usb[2];        // Y  axis
    writebuff[3]=0xFF;        //button  0xFF
    writebuff[4]=0xFF;        //button POV 0xFF



    HID_Write(&writebuff,5);


   }

}
```

and the Descriptor

```
const struct {
  char report[USB_HID_RPT_SIZE];
}
hid_rpt_desc =

     {0x05, 0x01, // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
     0x15, 0x00, // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
     0x09, 0x04, // USAGE (Joystick)
     0xA1, 0x01, // COLLECTION (Application)
     0x05, 0x02, // USAGE_PAGE (Simulation Controls)
     0x09, 0xBB, // USAGE (Throttle)
     0x15, 0x00, // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
     0x26, 0xFF, 0x00, // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (255)
     0x75, 0x08, // REPORT_SIZE (8)
     0x95, 0x01, // REPORT_COUNT (1)
     0x81, 0x02, // INPUT (Data Var Abs)
     0x05, 0x01, // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
     0x09, 0x01, // USAGE (Pointer)
     0xA1, 0x00, // COLLECTION (Physical)
     0x09, 0x30, // USAGE (X)
     0x09, 0x31, // USAGE (Y)
     0x95, 0x02, // REPORT_COUNT (2)
     0x81, 0x02, // INPUT (Data Var Abs)}
     0xC0, // END_COLLECTION
     0x09, 0x39, // USAGE (Hat switch)
     0x15, 0x00, // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
     0x25, 0x03, // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (3)
     0x35, 0x00, // PHYSICAL_MINIMUM (0)
     0x46, 0x0E, 0x01, // PHYSICAL_MAXIMUM (270)
     0x65, 0x14, // UNIT (Eng Rot:Angular Pos)
     0x75, 0x04, // REPORT_SIZE (4)
     0x95, 0x01, // REPORT_COUNT (1)
     0x81, 0x02, // INPUT (Data Var Abs)
     0x05, 0x09, // USAGE_PAGE (Button)
     0x19, 0x01, // USAGE_MINIMUM (Button 1)
     0x29, 0x0A, // USAGE_MAXIMUM (Button 10)
      0x15, 0x00, // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
      0x25, 0x01, // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
      0x75, 0x01, // REPORT_SIZE (1)
      0x95, 0x0C, // REPORT_COUNT (12) 2 bits added to switch report count
                  // so bytes are even. Bytes must be even.
      0x55, 0x00, // UNIT_EXPONENT (0)
      0x65, 0x00, // UNIT (None)
      0x81, 0x02, // INPUT (Data Var Abs)
0xC0 // END_COLLECTION
  };
```

Comment: Please use the "edit" button to clarify the statement of the problem.  Perhaps you need to give examples in the body of your question of data that works and doesn't, or of the sort of noise you are seeing.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The problem that I see is for example connecting just one analog sensor and leaving other floating, I see that X,Y Axis are also measuring, however I'm connecting to Analog sensor of Throttle only. That's from my guess, because I'm writing in one packet the OTHER non connected analog signals reading in one packet

Comment: a USB report contains all of the fields in the report descriptor ... it is possible that you do not have clear understanding of USB data exchange, so you are expecting something to happen, that will not happen in reality

Comment: If you don't have anything connected to an ADC channel then don't read that channel.  Send a safe dummy value instead if the protocol requires you to send something.  Or go ahead and keep reading the meaningless channel but throw away the reading and send a safe dummy value.

Comment: @jsotola Can you explain more please, I'm beginner

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have to send the packet of writebuffer, If I send less items it doesn't get recognized the USB. So how would I send dummy values :( ?

Comment: Change `writebuff[0]=usb[0];` to `writebuff[0]=0;` or whichever one you want to make dummy.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I get your point, but sometimes I want to hook up an analog sensor into the box, and want to read it, so I want to make a more robust analog sensor box, if there is an input read it, don't send dummy values if there are no sensors connected. Hope you get my point

Comment: You can try a very large pulldown resistor but it will distort the normal operation slightly.  Really you're better off with a mode switch.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I found that the issue is cross talk, but don't know how to solve it

Comment: Random values are to be expected on an undriven ADC input, not just because of "crosstalk".  As in the previous comment, you'll need to either have some sort of weak keeper resistor, or have a mode switch or different firmware or PC software which ignores the undesired value.