# Cross talk issue ADC PIC18F2458

Tags: microcontroller, pic, adc, c

I have used the following configuration according the data sheet

FOSC/32, 12 TAD

I still get cross talk, I'm using 3 ADC Channels with USB, and When I use one Channel, other channels get affected I mean they get readings too.

[image]
unsigned int ADC_read_implementation(int channel){

```
    unsigned int adval = 0;
    ADCON2.B7 = 1; //results right justified
    ADCON2.B0 = 0;
    ADCON2.B1 = 1;
    ADCON2.B2 = 1;
  
    ADCON2.B3 = 1;
    ADCON2.B4 = 1;
    ADCON2.B5 = 1;

    ADCON1 = 0x05;
    if ( channel == 1 )
    {
      ADCON0.CHS0 = 0x1;
      ADCON0.CHS2 = 0x0;
      ADCON0.CHS1 = 0x0;
      ADCON0.CHS3 = 0x0;
    }
    else if (channel == 8)
    {
      ADCON0.CHS0 = 0x0;
      ADCON0.CHS2 = 0x0;
      ADCON0.CHS1 = 0x0;
      ADCON0.CHS3 = 0x1;
    }
    else
    {
      ADCON0.CHS0 = 0x1;
      ADCON0.CHS2 = 0x0;
      ADCON0.CHS1 = 0x0;
      ADCON0.CHS3 = 0x1;
    }
    ADCON0.B0 = 1; //turn on ADC
    Delay_ms(10);
    ADCON0.GO_DONE = 1;
    while(ADCON0.GO_DONE == 1);
    adval = (ADRESH << 8) + ADRESL;
    return adval;
}
```

Crystal used is 4MHz

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39887c.pdf

Comment: _"When I use one Channel, other channels get affected"_ - by how much? Please provide example readings, and a schematic showing the analog input circuits.

Comment: If these are multiplexed inputs sharing the same ADC then making an ADC reading too quickly on a new channel will be error prone due to settling time.

Comment: @BruceAbbott The schematic is just a pot with 5V, GND, when I use for example Analog Input 1, I see reading on Analog Input 9. That shows when I send the data using USB Joystick, I see throttle axis is affected while I'm just using one POT for the X Axis

Comment: You still haven't answered my questions! What value is the pot? Do you have a pot on every input? Exactly how much crosstalk are you getting?

Comment: @BruceAbbott The POT is 10K, No I don't have a Pot on every Input. I don't know how much cross talk I don't know how to measure it, but what I see is Other Inputs are not connected but Only one Input is connected to POT, Other ADCs are read too and they get values, don't know from where they get. That's obvious in the USB Game Joy stick

Comment: So you have other inputs that are not connected to anything, and you get non-zero readings on them?

Comment: @BruceAbbott No, I have a USB Joystick using PIC, so I'm sending 3 readings one throttle, one X-Axis, one Y-AXIS, the POT is connected to Throttle Analog pin, when I use the resistor, I see that X-AXIS, Y-AXIS changing too, which is strange.There are nothing connected to them

Comment: _"No... There are nothing connected to them"_ - Sorry I don't understand. What does 'nothing connected' mean?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Not connected to the Analog Input signals, nothing connected to them, but I get values on the USB Joystick windows app, when I use just one analog POT

Comment: You arlready asked about this exact same issue of noise on the undriven analog inputs of your project at [Writing USB Joystick for PIC18F using MikroC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/536143/writing-usb-joystick-for-pic18f-using-mikroc) please do not re-post the same issue again, rather work with your yet-unresolved *existing* question, including by editing it to narrow the issue as your understanding of the problem develops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments you say,

> **Other Inputs are not connected** but Only one Input is connected to POT,
> Other ADCs are read too and they get values, don't know from where
> they get.

Below is a simplified model of the ADC analog input (taken from the PIC18F2458 datasheet):-

[image]

The analog input signal is fed through the channel multiplexer (ANx)  to the sampling switch, which closes at the beginning of the ADC acquisition cycle, causing the sample and hold capacitor `Chold` to charge up or down to match the input voltage. Charging current passes through the various resistances in the circuit, increasing the time it takes for the voltages to converge. To ensure that the holding capacitor charges quickly the source resistance should be low. Microchip recommends 2.5 kΩ or less.

But what happens if you don't connect *anything* to the analog input? With the input open circuit or 'floating' a random amount of charge will appear on the pin capacitor due to leakage and crosstalk from other nearby circuits. When the sampling switch closes the charges on `Cpin` and `Chold` will equalize, with a maximum voltage change of ~ Vdd / 6 due to the capacitance ratio. `Chold` already has the charge left on it from the previous acquisition, so unconnected analog inputs may give readings similar to, but not quite the same as the previous channel that was read.

If you don't want to see random values on unconnected channels then either don't read them, or apply a defined voltage to the pin through a suitably low resistance.

Comment: FYI the poster previously asked this at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/536143/writing-usb-joystick-for-pic18f-using-mikroc where it was explained that noise on undriven analog inputs is to be expected; rather than adopt a strategy to deal with that they seem to have simply re-posted the problem from scratch.